# What's the Win32 API to disable task manager completely?

Tags: c, winapi, taskmanager

That is,even if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>,the task manager should not pop up.

Comment: JK: `del \Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe`

Comment: @pmg ,LOL:) But seriously,is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is a system policy question,not a programming question. Redirecting to serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a user can go in and turn it on again, you can set this registry key to 1

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisableTaskmgr
```

(the \System\ and DisableTaskmgr might not exists so create them, DisableTaskmgr should be a DWORD32 key)

Comment: Somehow on Windows 7 this doesn't work without admin rights.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable access to the task manager using the [group policy editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882) or the [The Group Policy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To use the editor, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to Navigate to "User Configuration" -> "Administrative Templates" -> "System" -> "Ctrl+Alt+Del Options". Double-click the "Remove Task Manager" setting and set it to "Enabled".

Close the policy editor then run the command `gpupdate /force` to apply the changes.

After you've done this, if the user tries to access the task manager then they'll get a message saying that access is disabled.

**EDIT**

If the user is an administrator then they could (if they know how to) go into gpedit and re-enable the taskmanager. To avoid this make them a member of the Users or Guests groups: they won't be able to change the any policy settings then.

Comment: I think that WMI should provide a way to do this from code.

Comment: @Agnel Kurian - Added a link to the API docs

Answer (score 1):

You should normally not need to do that, and regardless, you should not do it anyway, even if think you need it. There are good reasons why the user is allowed to do things like tabbing out or killing processes with the task manager. Interfering with the system in such a fundamental way is usually frowned upon, for good reason. Even more so as there is really no valid reason why you'd need that, normally.

Anyway, there is no way to *directly* disable launching Taskmanager, but there are at least 3 *indirect* ways of doing this:

1. Install a global low-level keyboard hook and discard the Ctrl-Alt-Del keypress (this may not work on some versions of Windows, and if the user is running antivirus software, it will trigger an alert)
2. Install your own no-action Taskmanager (ProcessExplorer does that, so it ought to work)
3. Remove "read-execute" permission from the taskmanager executable (this works *confirmedly*, I've done that by accident once)

Obviously, all three "solutions" are super intrusive and have a super malicious character, so you should really think 10 times before doing any such thing. And if you do, don't complain if you break your system.

Comment: There must be some better solution,I've seen this kind of software before.

Comment: Well, "better" is kind of debatable. Like I said, there is normally no valid reason why you would need this at all. I can assure you from my experience (when I made a restricted user account that accidentially had no access to ProcessExplorer's exe) that it is _totally annoying_ if you press Ctrl-Alt-Del and nothing happens. Your end-users will hate you, if you do such a thing deliberately.

Comment: There could be valid reasons... such as when running a kiosk. Or when you have software running that you don't want the user to be allowed to disable. As another example, an application that records time since login in an internet parlor.

Comment: The OP isn't trying to disable Ctrl-Alt-Del, he's trying to disable access to the _task manager_.

Comment: @Andy Johnson: Sorry, my wording may have been slightly ambiguous, will edit that.

Comment: @Damon, the cltr+alt+del is the system call and could not be hijacked nor blocked. So the only way to stop taskmanager is to deactivate it from registry